# Custom join condition in JPA

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to specify custom join criteria in JPA (either jpql or via the criteria api?

```
select .. from .. join ... on (... <custom criteria> )
```

The reason i need this is because i would like to join a set of tables on a date range (one is a historical table with fact stacking)

** update **

It is possible to specify additional join conditions/ criteria in JPA (2.1 >). See accepted answer (zxcf).

Hibernate note: Although it is possible to specify additional join criteria either using JOIN .. ON  or programmatic-ally using javax.persistence.criteria.JOIN, you cannot using criteria which references a different table, only criteria that reference the same table (and not higher in the hierarchy) are supported please see : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7321

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use `JOIN` keyword unless you have explicit relationship between two entities - if you have relationship, you can use:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e JOIN e.projects p
```

You can additionaly narrow your `JOIN` by using `ON` keyword (please note that this applies to `JPA 2.1`):

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e JOIN e.projects p ON p.name LIKE 'As%'
```

If you want to define `JOIN` which connects two entities which does not have defined relationship you should use additional conditions in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e, Projects p WHERE e.projectId = p.id
```

*update*

If you use `EclipseLink` (or it's your JPA provider) in version 2.4 or higher then **you can** use custom conditions in `JOIN .. ON` clause as EclipseLink also supports usage of the ON clause between two root level objects.

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN MailingAddress a ON e.address = a.address
```

[Here's reference](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#ON)

Comment: conditions/ restrictions in where clauses only applies to implicit joins which are in general unusable. Solid answer

Answer (score 4):

I think Dobrowolski's answer needs to be updated for future reference, as that is a feature no more exclusively provided by EclipseLink (at least for what concerns unrelated entities). If you are using Hibernate (5.1 or higher), it's now possible to declare explicit joins on unrelated entities (i.e without an explicit [mapping](https://thorben-janssen.com/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/)) using JPQL/HQL, as you can see from this [example](https://thorben-janssen.com/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/):

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery("SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName, n.phoneNumber FROM Person p JOIN PhoneBookEntry n ON p.firstName = n.firstName AND p.lastName = n.lastName").getResultList();

for (Object[] result : results) {
    log.info(result[0] + " " + result[1] + " - " + result[2]);
}

em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```